# Get next minimum, greater than or equal to a given value for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

given the following Table1:

```
    RefID  intVal  SomeVal
    ----------------------
        1      10    val01
        1      20    val02
        1      30    val03
        1      40    val04
        1      50    val05
        2      10    val06
        2      20    val07
        2      30    val08
        2      40    val09
        2      50    val10
        3      12    val11
        3      14    val12
        4      10    val13
        5     100    val14
        5     150    val15
        5    1000    val16
```

and Table2 containing some RefIDs and intVals like

```
    RefID  intVal
    -------------
        1      11    
        1      28    
        2       9    
        2      50    
        2      51    
        4      11    
        5       1    
        5     150    
        5     151
```

need an SQL Statement to get the next greater intValue for each RefID and NULL if not found in Table1
following is the expected result

```
    RefID  intVal  nextGt  SomeVal 
    ------------------------------
        1      11      20  val01
        1      28      30  val03
        2       9      10  val06
        2      50      50  val10
        2      51    NULL   NULL
        4      11    NULL   NULL
        5       1     100  val14
        5     150     150  val15
        5     151    1000  val16
```

help would be appreciated !

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Derived table `a` retrieves minimal values from table1 given `refid` and `intVal` from table2; outer query retrieves someValue only.

```
select a.refid, a.intVal, a.nextGt, table1.SomeVal
from
(
    select table2.refid, table2.intval, min (table1.intVal) nextGt
      from table2
      left join table1
        on table2.refid = table1.refid
       and table2.intVal <= table1.intVal
     group by table2.refid, table2.intval
) a
-- table1 is joined again to retrieve SomeVal 
left join table1
  on a.refid = table1.refid
 and a.nextGt = table1.intVal
```

[Here is Sql Fiddle with live test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34837/2).

Comment: This is Incredible, Just what I was looking for! Thanks a lot @Nikola. This query help me to get the minimum value from 2 different tables with the similar ID. My first result was more than 500K, just after using your query with distinct function, my result was about 15K. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT
  RefID,
  intVal,
  NextGt,
  SomeVal,
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t2.RefID,
      t2.intVal,
      t1.intVal AS NextGt,
      t1.SomeVal,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.RefID, t2.intVal ORDER BY t1.intVal) AS rn
    FROM
      dbo.Table2 AS t2
      LEFT JOIN dbo.Table1 AS t1 ON t1.RefID = t2.RefID AND t1.intVal >= t2.intVal
  ) s
WHERE
  rn = 1
;
```

The derived table matches each `Table2` row with all `Table1` rows that have the same `RefID` and an `intVal` that is greater than or equal to `Table2.intVal`. Each subset of matches is ranked and the first row is returned by the main query.

The nested query uses an outer join, so that those `Table2` rows that have no `Table1` matches are still returned (with nulls substituted for the `Table1` columns).

Alternatively you can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT
  t2.RefID,
  t2.intVal,
  t1.intVal AS NextGt,
  t1.SomeVal
FROM
  dbo.Table2 AS t2
  OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      t1.intVal
    FROM
      dbo.Table1 AS t1
    WHERE
      t1.RefID = t2.RefID
      AND t1.intVal >= t2.intVal
    ORDER BY
      t1.intVal ASC
  ) AS t1
;
```

This method is arguably more straightforward: for each `Table2` row, get all matches from `Table1` based on the same set of conditions, sort the matches in the ascending order of `Table1.intVal` and take the topmost `intVal`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a join, group by, and a case statement, and a trick:

```
select t1.refid, t2.intval,
       min(case when t1.intval > t2.intval then t1.intval end) as min_greater_than_ref,
       substring(min(case when t1.intval > t2.intval
                          then right('00000000'+cast(t1.intval as varchar(255)), 8)+t1.SomeVal)
                     end)), 9, 1000)
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.refid = t2.refid
group by t1.refid, t2.intval
```

SO, the trick is to prepend the integer value to SomeValue, zero-padding the integer value (in this case to 8 characters).  You get something like:  "00000020val01".  The minimum on this column is based on the minimum of the integer.  The final step is to extract the value.

For this example, I used SQL Server syntax for the concatenation.  In other databases you might use CONCAT() or ||.