# Find the first row where all three values have increased

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Given this dataset

```
declare @TestData Table
(
  Time int,
  Temp_Front int, 
  Temp_Center int, 
  Temp_Back int
);

insert into @TestData 
values 
    (2, 26, 27, 27), 
    (3, 26, 28, 27), 
    (4, 27, 28, 27), 
    (5, 27, 28, 28);


select Time ,
  Temp_Front , 
  Temp_Center , 
  Temp_Back   from @TestData
```

I need to find the first row where all three Temp value are greater than the temp values of the first row.

So Temp_Front > 26, Temp_centre > 27, Temp_back > 27.

I've tried a lot of stuff  and I always ends up with a lot of variables. And a lot of mess.

I won't mud the picture with this. So I just included the problem and the dataset.

Comment: how do you define *first row*?

Comment: I'm assuming 'first row' is determined by the 'time' field?

Comment: Correct Daniel. Sorry for omitting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  I would approach this as:

```
with first_row as (
      select top (1) td.*
      from @testdata td
      order by time
     )
select top (1) td.*
from @testdata td cross join
     first_row fr
where td.temp_front > fr.temp_front and
      td.temp_center > fr.temp_center and
      td.temp_back > fr.temp_back
order by time asc;
```

I don't find that window functions are particularly helpful for this problem.

If you were to use window functions:

```
select top (1) td.*
from (select td.*,
             first_value(temp_front) over (order by time) as fr_temp_front,
             first_value(temp_center) over (order by time) as fr_temp_center,
             first_value(temp_back) over (order by time) as fr_temp_back
      from @testdata td
     ) td
where td.temp_front > fr_temp_front and
      td.temp_center > fr_temp_center and
      td.temp_back > fr_temp_back
order by time asc;
```

Comment: Hmmn the price of the one with window function is only half compared to the cross join function

Comment: You need to handle case, when first row is max row. You shouldnt display it. My answer was very same, this case handled. And, my query was written originally by me. Its very strange, why our answers became very same :)

Comment: @JensBorrisholt . . . Interesting about the performance.  Do you have an index on `time`?  With such an index, I would expect the first version to have the better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate row numbers and use conditional aggregation to get the values on the first row. This can then be used for comparison to get the first such row which meets the criteria mentioned using `TOP` and `ORDER BY`.

```
with first_row as 
(
  select t.*, row_number() over(order by time) as rnum from @TestData t
)
select top 1 Time, Temp_Front, Temp_Center, Temp_Back
from 
    (
        select f.*, 
                max(case when rnum=1 then Temp_Front end) over() as first_tempfront,
                max(case when rnum=1 then Temp_Center end) over() as first_tempcenter,
                max(case when rnum=1 then Temp_Back end) over() as first_tempback
        from first_row f
    ) Dummy
where 
  temp_front > first_tempfront and temp_center > first_tempcenter and temp_back > first_tempback
order by rnum
```

Comment: This answer is much more complicated than it needs to be.  For instance, `first_value()` would simplify the logic.

Comment: totally missed it..just saw you added in a version with first_value.

Comment: I like the version with FIRST_VERSION better because it's simpler :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late response. You may use this:

```
;with [min] as (
    select top 1 
        [Time], [Temp_Front], [Temp_Center], [Temp_Back] 
    from
        @TestData 
    order  by 
         [Time] asc     
)
select top 1 
    [t].[Time], [t].[Temp_Front], [t].[Temp_Center], [t].[Temp_Back] 
from 
    @TestData   as [t]
cross join
    [min]       as [m]
where 
        ([t].[Time]         <>  [m].[Time])
    and [t].[Temp_Front]    >   [m].[Temp_Front]            
    and [t].[Temp_Center]   >   [m].[Temp_Center]
    and [t].[Temp_Back]     >   [m].[Temp_Back]
order by [Time] asc;
```

Full testing query: https://pastebin.com/3Hx33SfX

Answer (score 0):

JOIN to a derived table consisting of only the first row, and check all three columns in the WHERE clause or JOIN condition.   Use `TOP 1` to get only the first row that satisfies the condition.

Comment: I've looked at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736813/get-next-minimum-greater-than-or-equal-to-a-given-value-for-each-group

Which basically does what you are suggestion. But I cant get it to work (compile)

Comment: Can you add your attempt to use this strategy to your question, and the error you got, so we can see where you went wrong and fix it?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt  btw, Gordon's answer, which you accepted, is exactly what I was suggesting in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If, i understand correctly you can also use `sum` of *temp* values

```
with cte as (
    select *, (select sum(temp_values) 
               from (values (Temp_Front), (Temp_center), (Temp_back))a(temp_values)) as Maxnum
    from  @TestData t
)

select * 
from cte c
where Maxnum = (select MAX(Maxnum) from cte);
```

Comment: Then I haven't been clear enough! I can not  use a sum, because I need to be sure that all three values have increased not only the sum of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a loop:

```
declare @minrow int = (select min(time) from @testdata)
declare @iterator int = @minrow+1
declare @tempfront varchar(max)
declare @tempcenter varchar(max)
declare @tempback varchar(max)
declare @originaltempfront varchar(max)=(select  temp_front from  @testdata where time=@minrow)
declare @originaltempcenter varchar(max)=(select  temp_center from  @testdata where time=@minrow)
declare @originaltempback varchar(max) =(select  temp_back from  @testdata where time=@minrow)

while @iterator<= (select max(time) from @testdata)
begin
select @tempfront= temp_front from  @testdata where time=@iterator
select @tempcenter= temp_center from  @testdata where time=@iterator
select @tempback= temp_back from  @testdata where time=@iterator

if exists(select 1 from @testdata where @tempfront>@originaltempfront and @tempback>@originaltempback
and @tempcenter>@originaltempcenter and time=@iterator)
select * from @testdata where @tempfront>@originaltempfront and @tempback>@originaltempback
and @tempcenter>@originaltempcenter and time=@iterator
if @@rowcount <> 0 break

set @iterator=@iterator+1
end
```

Comment: That was more or less where I started :)